# In VB.Net, how can I get an editable collection for multiple variable types

Tags: vb.net, collections

Having done multiple searches, here and elsewhere, I'm more confused now than when I started.
I'm obviously wrong but I thought it wouldn't be too difficult to get a collection that could do the following:

Accept different variable types:
String, Integer, byte

Accept new items and allow removing of items (Add, Remove)

Be searchable:  (Something like)

```
For each str in collection 
    If collection.contains(xy) then
     do something
    End if
```

Be editable:  (Something like)

If collection.Firstring = "XY" then
Collection.SecondString = AB
End If

I realise that this might be a silly question but having tried List(Of), Hashtable, Dictionary and a separate Class, all appear to do some of the above but I can't find the correct one.
I'm using VS 2019 and .Net 4.5

I don't have a full understanding of collections, and would appreciate some suggestions to see where I'm going wrong.

Many Thanks

Comment: The different generic collections have different characteristics based on the underlying storage type, so the right one to use really depends on what your usage patterns will be.  `List` is contiguous storage, so fast random access, linear search.  `Dictionary` and `Set` are hashed storage, so extremely fast lookup but not necessarily in-order iteration (and dependent on the hash function which can have performance impacts).  There are some other options that have some additional different trade-offs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  The number of items would be small so speed I don't think would be an issue.  Multiple types I think is the most important factor though, could you suggest what might be the most suitable to research based on that?

Comment: If by "multiple types" you mean you want to store different types in the same collection, why do you want to do that?  It's seldom the best approach.

Comment: Please see my comment below as to what I'm trying to achieve.  Thanks

Comment: All the answers and comments below seem to have disappeared?

Comment: I explained below what I'm trying to achieve.  I was looking for a collection that has String1, String2 and Byte.   As the program loads I will add 3000 known strings to String1 and dummy values to String2 and Byte as I don't know what they are yet.  The user will add and update String2 and Byte based on the value of String1.   The values of String1 will not change, but more String1/String2/Byte might sometimes be added.   Many thanks, hope that is clearer.

Comment: So it seems like what you really want to do is to store a derived type (either the tuple of string1, string 2, and byte or the tuple of string 2 and byte) in an indexed container.  You should use a `Dictionary(of TKey, TValue)` with string 1 as the key and the tuple as the value.  You can either use one of the `Tuple` types or make your own `Class` or `Structure` to hold string 2 and the byte.

Comment: You tried HashSet(of Object)? Or if order matters, List(of Object)? As others have pointed out, I almost never work with mixed types in the same collection.

Comment: I think you have a question about how to do something specific but should likely be questioning your desired implementation. There is likely a better way to do what you are intending than what you are after. A list of different types without context is generally a poor idea as once the list leaves the scope of where it was created, its usefulness becomes arbitrary. A custom business object, tuple, etc would be a better option most likely.

Comment: *"Please see my comment below as to what I'm trying to achieve"*. No. No one should have to read the comments to understand the question. Edit your question and provide all the relevant information there. You can then add a comment saying that you've updated the question, so those who have already commented will be notifified.

Comment: OK, so I detailed exactly the type of collection I needed and included some code to try and illustrate this.  Then a user said this was not detailed enough needed context.  So I did that. Then another user said "If we knew what you were trying to achieve, we could help"  So I did that.  Another wanted that also, so I referred them to that post.  Then half of the answers/comments disappeared. Editing the question continually based on different views of whats needed isnt practicable. I think Craig and Clueless read the whole thing. v helpful.  I'm researching those. Apologies for upsetting jm

Answer (score 1):

Why doesn't List(of Object) meet your needs?

```
Dim collection As New List(Of Object)

' You can add values
collection.Add("s1")
collection.Add("s2")
collection.Add(CByte(3))
collection.Add("s4")
collection.Add(CByte(5))
collection.Add(CByte(6))

' And remove values
collection.Remove(CByte(5))

' And search for values
Console.WriteLine($"Is 5 in collection? {collection.Contains(CByte(5))}")
Console.WriteLine($"Is 6 in collection? {collection.Contains(CByte(6))}")
Console.WriteLine($"Is s1 in collection? {collection.Contains("s1")}")
Console.WriteLine($"Is s9 in collection? {collection.Contains("s9")}")

' And access values at specific positions
If collection(0) = "s1" Then
    ' And replace values at specific positions
    collection(1) = "replacement"
End If

Console.WriteLine("Contents of collection:")
For Each obj In collection
    Console.WriteLine($"  {obj} ({obj.GetType().Name})")
Next
```

The example code generates this output:

```
Is 5 in collection? False
Is 6 in collection? True
Is s1 in collection? True
Is s9 in collection? False
Contents of collection:
  s1 (String)
  replacement (String)
  3 (Byte)
  s4 (String)
  6 (Byte)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class to contain your properties:

```
Public Class Form1
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim myCollection As New List(Of MyCustomClass)

    For i As Integer = 0 To 10
      myCollection.Add(New MyCustomClass With {.StringProperty = $"StringValue{i}"})
    Next i

    Dim c6 = (From itm In myCollection Where itm.StringProperty = "StringValue6" Select itm).SingleOrDefault
    If c6 IsNot Nothing Then
      c6.IntegerProperty = 6
    End If
    MsgBox($"{c6.StringProperty}, {c6.IntegerProperty}")
  End Sub

  Class MyCustomClass
    Property StringProperty As String
    Property IntegerProperty As Integer
    Property ByteProperty As Byte
  End Class
End Class
```